# Write Latin and non-Latin language without changing order(eg; always write from left side)

Tags: python, pandas, text, urdu, non-latin

Like if I have a string in English + Urdu language

```
name = "جیمز is my name"
print(name)
```

The Output I'll get is:  **is my name جیمز**

How Can I change this to: **جیمز is my name**

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please tell us your Python version, OS and terminal encoding!

Comment: Sir, The python version is 3.8.8. encoding 'UTF-8' actually i am asking for is there any approach that can fixed it to always write from left side.

Comment: You gave 1 of the 3 things I requested.

Comment: python version 3.8.8 ,encoding UTF-8 ,OS Windows 10

Comment: On Windows this might simply be an issue with the terminal which can not handle RTL properly.

Comment: Alright! Thanks